# strange DNS query on the fw/gateway

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, windows-server-2016

I would like to ask what could be wrong with my server. I have a Windows Server 2016 server (DC + DNS server for a local network). It has IPv4 and static routable IPv6 address configured and althoug it has a loopback configured as a DNS server, I can see this on my gateway/firewall:

`DNS: query [<<< SERVERS PUBLIC IPv6 ADDRESS >>>]:58414 -> [fec0:0:0:ffff::1]:53 for 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa`

`DNS: query [<<< SERVERS PUBLIC IPv6 ADDRESS >>>]:58414 -> [fec0:0:0:ffff::2]:53 for 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa`

`DNS: query [<<< SERVERS PUBLIC IPv6 ADDRESS >>>]:58414 -> [fec0:0:0:ffff::3]:53 for 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa`

fec0:0:0:ffff::1, fec0:0:0:ffff::2, fec0:0:0:ffff::3 are automatic Windows DNS addresses, which shouldn't be used when I have DNS server configured on my server. Am I right?

Comment: `fec0::/10` is deprecated so it really shouldn't be used. The [registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml) says: *Deprecated by [[RFC3879](http://www.iana.org/go/rfc3879)] in September 2004. Formerly a Site-Local scoped address prefix.*

Comment: I know it's deprecated, but it's obviously still used in Windows. I'm asking why my server using those IPs, when I have DNS server specified on the interface. Windows usually uses those IPs when there is no DNS server configured...